# How can i work with flow inside repository android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I wrote code which works fine without kotlin flow, but i want to try kotlin flow and when i used it inside repository but somehow it is not even entering inside i could not find any solution since it is not throwing any error, it is just not entering inside function and i think it is because of flow collector. It is coming till repository but for repo it is not entering.

```
class NewsRepositoryImpl(private val newsService: NewsService) : NewsRepository {
override suspend fun getNews(search: String): Flow<ResultWrapper<List<Article>>> = flow {
    emit(ResultWrapper.Loading)
    try {
        val news = newsService.getNews(search, BuildConfig.API_KEY)
        emit(ResultWrapper.Success(news.articles.map { it.toArticle() }))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(ResultWrapper.Error(e.message))
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `flow` builder you create a cold stream of data. The code inside it is executed only when the flow is being collected, i.e. [terminal operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#terminal-flow-operators) invoked, for example `collect`, `collectLatest`, `first`... .

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    newsRepository.getNews("news").collectLatest { result ->
        // use result
    }
}
```